# LinearGradientBrush spin

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I have a LinearGradientBrush and am trying to apply the RotateTransform offset to it. With this code, it rotates and keeps still at the angle I give it:

```
<LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="60" CenterY="30" Angle="45" />
</LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
```

Is there a way to make the "Angle" dynamic so the brush will spin at 180 degrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a DoubleAnimation on the `Angle` property of the RotateTransform, like in the example below, where the LinearGradientBrush fills a Rectangle, and the the animation is started when the Rectangle is loaded, and then runs forever:

```
<Rectangle Width="300" Height="300">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
            <LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="150" CenterY="150"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush.Transform>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Transform.Angle"
                        To="360" Duration="0:0:5" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```